# How to specify c/c++ compiler on stack install command

Tags: haskell, installation, configuration, haskell-stack

I'm learning Haskell and I'm setting up my system for development.
I'm on MacOS and trying to install `hoogle` locally with `stack install hoogle` fails because the compilation of some libraries fails with the error

```
error: gcc-13: error: unrecognized command-line option '--target=x86_64-apple-darwin--lflag=--target=x86_64-apple-darwin'
```

I'm pretty sure that the error is due to the fact that I have multiple C/C++ compilers in my system and the compilation is using `gcc-13` (which is linked to GCC 13.2.0) rather than `gcc` (the system compiler which is linked to clang 15.0.0)

My intuition has been further confirmed by installing `hoogle` first with `cabal install hoogle`, which led to the same error, and then with `cabal install hoogle --with-gcc=/usr/bin/gcc` which successfully installed it.

I was then wondering if it was somehow possible to specify the C compiler used by `stack`

Comment: Stack also has [a `with-gcc` option](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/global_flags/#-with-gcc-option), which might be what you need.

Comment: Although I checked out documentation I totally missed it, guess I was looking on the wrong place. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment by [@duplode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2751851/duplode) there's a `--with-gcc`flag that allows to specify the desired C compiler that `stack` uses